# Visual Studio code debugging not working based on Angular Tutorial

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am moving from AnguarJS to Angular, and using Visual Studio code to experiment.

I followed the instructions precisely in VS Code's tutorial [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/angular-tutorial), but I can't get debugging working. First I run `ng serve` at the console, and then press F5 at launch chrome.  (The VS Code - Debugger for Chrome Extension is enabled).  Then Press F5 and launch Chrome.

**The symptom is I can't set a breakpoint.** I get an orange circle which changes to an empty circle next to the line title = 'Hello World'.  That's my main question.

One thing I don't understand is why I don't see any generated javascript fils on my local machine Nor do I see a map file.  Does ng-serve generate the javascript files but it doesn't save them?  But also I don't see a map file generated, so does that have something to do with why debugging break points aren't enabled?

The MS tutorial referenced above has all the code, but the relevant module in which I am trying to set the break point is below.  Nothing much to it:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Hello Fold';  // . <-- Tried set breakpoint here.
}
```

Launch configuration specified in the tutorial is:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

The launch.json  doesn't include any "attach" config,  so I wonder how debugging is meant to be enabled, would appreciate understanding what was supposed to happen here, and hopefully, a clue about what's failing.

One other post here suggested what looks to be a more complete launch config, but it doesn't work either:  To use it I first run `ng-serve` at the console, then `Launch Chrome against localhost with sourcemaps`, then `Attach to Chrome with sourcemaps` attach, but the breakpoints still aren't enabled in the source code pane, only empty circles.

```
 {
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "userDataDir": "${workspaceRoot}/.vscode/chrome",
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*" }
    },
    {
        "name": "Attach to Chrome, with sourcemaps",
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "attach",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "port": 9222,
        "sourceMaps": true,
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "sourceMapPathOverrides": { "webpack:/*": "${webRoot}/*" }
    }]}
```

Here is the environment I am working in:

```
Angular CLI: 8.3.21
Node: 11.2.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.21
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.21
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.21
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.21
@angular/cli                      8.3.21
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.21
@schematics/angular               8.3.21
@schematics/update                0.803.21
rxjs                              6.4.0
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem turns out to be trivial newbie mistake, although not that easy to figure out if you are unfamiliar with what Angular file structure is supposed to look like.   The tutorial says:

> You can now create a new Angular application by typing:
>
> ```
> ng new my-app
> ```
>
> my-app is the name of the folder for your application

My mistake was to create the project folder in the console, not realizing the ng new will create the folder for the project itself.   So when I started VS Code inside the new directory I created, and then ran `ng new my-app`, I created a subfolder of the same name, into which all the projects files were put.

When you create the `launch.json` file though it gets placed in the workspace root, when it's supposed to be in the same folder with the rest of the project files, not one level above.  Hope this saves somebody else some confusion...